# Nan instead of value- writing to file

Tags: c++, loops, ifstream, ofstream

I am a beginner programmer and I have a class assignment where I am supposed to read info from a file, and then manipulate that data and write it to another file. 
I got the output file to print, but instead of the values I calculated, it returns Nan. I'm not sure if it's because it's not reading the values from the input file, or if my loop isn't working correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
void linreg(ifstream &fin, double &m, double &b, double &r, double &firstx, 
double &lastx)
{
   // 1) reduction variable initialization
   double sumx, sumy, sumxx, sumxy, sumyy, x, y;
   sumx = 0;
   sumy = 0;
   sumxx = 0;
   sumxy = 0;
   sumyy = 0;

   // 2) loop forever
   for(;;)
   {
      // 3) attempt to input an ordered pair
      fin >> x >> y;

      // 4) test for end of file
      if(fin.eof())
      {
        // 5) leave when true
      break;
      }
      else
      {
       continue;
       }
     // 6) test for first iteration
      if(n==0)
      {
         // 7) save lower limit of integration
      x = firstx;
      }
         // 8) save upper limit of integration
      else{
      x = lastx;
      }
      // 9) update reduction variables
      sumx = sumx + x;
      sumy = sumy + y;
      sumxx = sumxx + x * x;
      sumxy = sumxy + x * y;
      sumyy = sumyy + y * y;

    }

   // 10) calculate slope, y intercept and correlation coefficient
   m = ((sumx * sumy) - (n * sumxy)) / ((sumx * sumx) - (n * sumxx));
   b = (sumy - (m * sumx)) / n;
   r = ((n * sumxy) - (sumx * sumy)) / (sqrt(((n * sumxx) - (sumx * sumx))*
((n * sumyy) - (sumy * sumy))));

}
```

Also, I'm sorry if my code is hard to read, I'm still learning!

Comment: What did you observe when you stepped through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: Read like this: `while (fin >> x >> y) { if (n == 0) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

The `else { continue; }` clause skips the rest of your loop.  Nothing below that line is executed.

Now, normally, the compiler would be issuing a warning telling you that `if(n==0)` is unreachable code, meaning that it will never be executed.

The fact that you did not see this warning means that you are trying to program without warnings enabled.  Do not try to do that, it will not amount to any good.  Try compiling with the `-Wall` switch, or look at the documentation of your compiler to see how to enable all warnings.

**EDIT**

Furthermore, you do `fin >> x >> y;` and then `if(fin.eof())`, but that won't work: you must first check for EOF, *then* read from the stream.

Furthermore, `if(n==0) { x = firstx; } else { x = lastx; }` will always overwrite `x` with something, that's probably not what you want to do, though I do not know what it is that you want to do

Comment: Thank you! I removed the else statement, but now it is returning infinity for these values. Do you think the break statement isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Yor code will break or continue every iteration

```cpp
if(fin.eof())
  {
    // 5) leave when true
  break;
  }
  else
  {
   continue;
   }
```